# error al insertar datos en php (imagen, texto)

Tags: php, mysql, imagen

Estoy creando un blog y me base en un vídeo para empezar, hice un formulario en donde se van a llenar datos para guardarlos en una base de datos para posteriormente mostrarlos en otra interfaz, mi problema radica que me manda error en la linea numero 25 al momento de querer insertar una imagen en la base de datos, aqui esta el codigo, campo_titulo y campo_descripcion son los nombres de los input del formulario, Titulo, Fecha, Descripcion, Imagen son los nombres de los campos de la base de datos.

```
     $host ="localhost";
     $usuario = "root";
     $clave = "";
     $bd = "seguridad";

     $conexion = mysqli_connect($host,$usuario,$clave,$bd);

    if ($_FILES['imagen'] ['error'] ) {
    switch ($_FILES ['imagen'] ['error'] ) {
    case 1 :
    echo "El envio del archivo se a interrumpido";
    break;
    case 2 :
    echo "No se envio el archivo debido a una lenta conexión";
    break;
                                      }

     } else {
    echo "No hay error en la trasnferencia de archivo";
    if ( (isset ($_FILES ['imagen'] ['name']) && ($_FILES ['ímagen'] 
    ['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OR) ) {
        $destino_de_ruta="imagenes/"; //me presenta eror aqui

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES ['imagen'] ['temp_name'], $destino_de_ruta . 
    $_FILES ['imagen'] ['name']);
        echo "el archivo se a copiado en el directorio de imagenes";


    }

    }

   $titulo = $_POST['campo_titulo'];
   $fecha = date ("y-m-d");
   $descripcion = $_POST['area_descripcion'];
   $imagen =$_FILES ['imagen'] ['name'];

  mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO contenido (Titulo, Fecha, Descripcion, 
  Imagen) values 
   ('$titulo', '$fecha', '$descripcion', '$imagen')");
  echo "Se agrego tu publicació´n con exito";


  ?>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la línea 11 y cuál es el error? Por favor pulsa en [edit] para indicar esos detalles poniendo en la pregunta el mensaje completo de error en texto.

Comment: ya lo solucione amigo muchas gracias, pero actualmente me da error en la linea 25 que es move_uploaded_file($_FILES ['imagen'] ['tmp_name'], $destino_de_ruta . $_FILES ['imagen'] ['name']);
    echo "el archivo se a copiado en el directorio de imagenes";   el error que me da php dice Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'move_uploaded_file' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\tesis\insertarcontenido.php on line 25

Comment: Te falta el punto y coma que cierra la línea anterior. Debería estar así: `$destino_de_ruta="imagenes/";`

Comment: Amigo le puse el punto y coma pero me vota el error syntax error unexpected ";"

Comment: Tienes más errores. Por ejemplo aquí: `$destino_de_ruta . $_FILES ['imagen'] ['name']);` no deberías tener un paréntesis antes del punto y coma. Deberías hacer una revisión minuciosa de tu código, porque son errores básicos, de sintaxis.

Comment: move_uploaded_file($_FILES ['imagen'] ['temp_name'], $destino_de_ruta . $_FILES ['imagen'] ['name']) lo cerre por que pense que se cerraba por la variable $_FILES, pero no logro encontrar mas errores :(

Comment: Pulsa en [edit]  y pon el código como lo tienes ahora para revisarlo.

Comment: ya lo puse amigo muchas  gracias

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar si los dos `if` que tienes significan que el código debe entrar en uno o en otro bloque? Es que primero tienes esto: `if ($_FILES['imagen'] ['error'] ) {`, luego tienes un `else` descolgado con respecto a ese `if` y luego abres este otro `if ( (isset ($_FILES ['imagen'] ['name']) && ($_FILES ['imagen'] 
    ['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OR) ) {` hay confusión en esos dos `if`. ¿Podrías explicar lo que quieres evaluar realmente para tratar de corregir el código?

Comment: queria evaluar si es que no hay error al momento de insertar la imagen y luego proceder a moverla y a insertarla con otros campos mas

Comment: despues de un minucioso estudio logre arreglarlo, resulto que me faltaba un parentesis y la funcion no era upload_er_or si no upload_er_ok jajaj tengo que practicar mas, gracias amigo por querer ayudarme

Comment: Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. Aquí estamos para ayudar en lo que se pueda. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Parte de mi formulario HTML

```
<label>Seleccionar un archivo</label>
<div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" name="subirRecursoAlumno" class="custom-file-input" id="subirRecursoAlumno">
    <label class="custom-file-label estiloCajaDeTexto" for="subirRecursoAlumno">Seleccione 
        un archivo</label>
</div>
```

Mi codigo PHP

```
// pregunto si viene el archivo desde el formulario
$archivo = ( isset( $_FILES['subirRecursoAlumno'] ) ) ? $_FILES['subirRecursoAlumno'] : null;
if ( $archivo["name"] != "" )   // pregunto si viene un archivo
{
    // directorio en donde voy a guardar el archivo
    $directorio  = "recursos/alumnos/curso";

    // creo una variable donde se guardará la ruta del archivo
    $ruta_destino_archivo = $directorio . "/" . {$archivo['name']};

    $archivo_ok = move_uploaded_file( $archivo['tmp_name'], $ruta_destino_archivo );

    //  move_uploaded_file() devolverá true o false, dependiendo de si se pudo o no mover el archivo

    if ( $archivo_ok )
    {
        //código para cuando se sube el archivo
    }
    else
    {
        //código para cuando NO SE SUBE TU ARCHIVO
    }
}
```